# Just out of curiosity - Could someone explain the oddities of setTimeout() to me?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

By oddities, I mean these two things:

1. Functions in the first parameter need to be surrounded by
   quotations, or else the delay is set to 0 (Everything is executed
   instantly).
2. Everything after the timeout needs to have a delay after it as
       well, or else it is executed prior to the timeout finishing.

If there's a way around #2 - that would be awesome, but right now I'm just curious on this.

Short snippet to explain what I'm talking about:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) setTimeout("addInput('.')",i*500);
setTimeout('addInput("</br>")',5100);
```

In the above, unless addInput('.') is surrounded by quotations, the delay is ignored and the code is just executed; also unless I add a timeout to the second line, it will be executed before the first timeout is finished.

Comment: Well, `addInput('.')` in quotes is a string declaration and without a function call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Functions in the first parameter need to be surrounded by quotations,
>   or else the delay is set to 0 (Everything is executed instantly).

Not necessarily. In fact it is recommended to use the overload which takes directly a function pointer instead of a string to avoid the overhead of parsing it:

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        addInput('.');
    }, i * 500);
}
```

or its equivalent (warning: doesn't work in IE):

```
for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    setTimeout(addInput, i * 500, '.');
}
```

The following [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) overload is the one that is most commonly used:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

Comment: Note that passing extra arguments to `setTimeout` (to be passed to the callback upon invocation) [does not work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) in IE.

Comment: @josh3736, thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my answer to include this valuable information.

Comment: Very interesting, thank-you! Do you happen to have an answer for the second part of my question as well? - Or will using the function properly as suggested solve that?

Answer (score 4):

setTimeout takes a function reference.  That means you need to pass it the name of a function or an anonymous function, not the result of executing a function.

So this works:

```
setTimeout(fn, 1000);
```

But, this does not:

```
setTimeout(fn(), 1000);
```

The second example executes `fn()` immediately and passes the return value from that function to `setTimeout()` which is usually not what you want (you get no delay).

If you need to pass a parameter to your function, then you need to wrap it in a container function like this because setTimeout will call your function with no parameters:

```
setTimeout(function() {addInput('.')}, i*500);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That's because you are calling the function first, then sending the return value to the `setTimeout` method. You can use just the function name, or if you need to send in parameters, make an anonymous function:

   setTimeout(function() { addInput('.') }, i*500);
2. The `setTimeout` method doesn't delay the code, it puts the code in the callback of a timer. The code following the `setTimeout` call follows immediately.